# Onboarding - how to prioritize key action

Tags: android, material-design

I would like to implement the Quickstart onboarding experience in my application as detailed here:
https://material.google.com/growth-communications/onboarding.html#onboarding-quickstart

More specifically, I would like to prioritize my key action, a floating action button, as shown in the following screenshot:
https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B7WCemMG6e0VYmdoeTFfMTZPWVk/patterns_usereducation_06_SomethingToDoDo2.png

Are there any examples out there which implement this behaviour? Or at least some vector graphic which I can use as a background? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in that direction except for this single screenshot.

On a more general note, doesn't Google provide some sort of kitchensink where they show how to implement their own guidelines?